# X11 Shift + Tab keysym?

Tags: c, linux, unix, x11, xlib

How to detect `Shift + Tab` in `Xlib`? I'm able to match `KeySym` with `XK_Tab`, but it's not matching while holding shift to then check for `ev->state & ShiftMask`, so I'm kind of lost.

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to  Erdal Küçük's answer I was able to come up with the following function that detects Shift + Tab:

```
int detectShiftTab(XKeyEvent *xkey) {
    return XLookupKeysym(xkey, 0) == XK_Tab && xkey->state & ShiftMask;
}
```

Comment: Do you receive a key event if you press the Tab key (while holding the Shift key) but the `state` field does not contain the `ShiftMask`, or do you not receive a key event at all? Could you show some code? What is the sequence of key events you receive (KeyPress/KeyRelease, KeySym, state)?

Comment: Looks like Shift+Tab is tranlated to ISO_Left_Tab by X11 before reporting to client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple test, i realized that the `ShiftMask` is not reported on a `KeyPress` of the Shift key. Other than that, the `ShiftMask` is always set.

```
int main()
{
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    
    Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), 0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, 0);

    XSetWindowAttributes attr = { .event_mask = (KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask) };
    XChangeWindowAttributes(dpy, win, CWEventMask, &attr);

    XMapWindow(dpy, win);

    while (1) {
        XEvent evt;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &evt);

        switch (evt.type) {

            case KeyPress:
            printf(
                "key press: %s shiftmask: %d\n", 
                XKeysymToString(XLookupKeysym(&evt.xkey, 0)), 
                (evt.xkey.state & ShiftMask) == ShiftMask
            );
            break;

            case KeyRelease:
            printf(
                "key release: %s shiftmask: %d\n", 
                XKeysymToString(XLookupKeysym(&evt.xkey, 0)), 
                (evt.xkey.state & ShiftMask) == ShiftMask
            );
            break;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output (typing Shift + Tab):

```
key press:   Shift_L shiftmask: 0
key press:   Tab shiftmask: 1
key release: Tab shiftmask: 1
key release: Shift_L shiftmask: 1
```